# Hadoop upgrade issue with web monitoring

Tags: hadoop

I just upgraded from 0.19 to 0.20 everything seems fine however the web monitoring tool doesn't work any more:

`http://mydomain.com:50070/webapps/hdfs/dfshealth.jsp`

Gives me a `404`.

Same stands for the job tracking tool

Any idea where to look at ?

Comment: There is a similar issue [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128153/cant-access-hadoop-web-ui-for-job-tracker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically re-installed Hadoop 0.20.2 from scratch.
Nota : did not use the Nutch1.2 build to install to have it clean and is probably.

Also to note : 
+ startup of cluster is much slower, so one has to wait some time (eg 1 minute) before the dfs is running so it may give the impression it is not working
+ same stand for the start of mapred which does wait for the dfs to run and takes its own time.

Eventually everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Hadoop 0.20 and my url to jobtracker is:

http://mydomain.com:50070/dfshealth.jsp

Basically going to http://mydomain.com:50070/ should redirect you to correct url.